# Passing argument from one plugin to another

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have one extension that has 2 plugins. I would to pass an argument from plugin1 to plugin2.

In plugin1's view I generate a link to a page where a content element for plugin2 is inserted:

```
<f:link.action controller="ApplicationController" action="showFormAction" arguments="{test: 1}" pageUid="40">Link</f:link.action>
```

In `ApplicationController` I try to retrieve the test parameter like this:

```
$this->request->getArgument('test');
```

But I get this error:

> `#1176558158`: An argument "test" does not exist for this request.

Is there a way to solve or debug this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to set `pluginName="Plugin2Name"` in your `f:link.action` viewhelper call. You can see that the link currently contains the desired argument but with the namespace of the 1st plugin. If you add `pluginName`, the namespace will be changed to the 2nd plugin.

Comment: As documented in code: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Link/ActionViewHelper.php#L55

Comment: Thx for fast reply